# How to make node disappear

Tags: materials, node-editor, shortcut, mathematics, groups

[image]

It seems to make the value node disappear while connecting it to group input. I've tried different combinations and have node wrangler on but I'm not sure how to get it. I'm also unclear as to exactly what it does, that you couldn't do without the shortcut. From [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3rX-C5C4xlI).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First they use a Node Wrangler shortcut.  They're doing a <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> and drawing a line over the two noodles coming out of the *Value* node.

This command combines the two noodles into a *Reroute* node that splits out to its two destinations.

Then they delete the *Value* node and bring a new input over from the *Group Input*.  Essentially they've recreated the *Value* node as a slider on the node group.

Comment: thank you! also funny and fitting those lines are called noodles.